# Disturbance field of a rotating particle in still water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, viscosity, navier-stokes

Consider a solid particle $B$ in the whole space filled with steady still water. The particle rotates around herself with an imposed moment $\tau \in \mathbb{R}^3$. As the Reynold number of the flow is very low, I can modelize the disturbance fluid using steady stokes equations.

I want to study the following equation, $u$ is the water velocity and $p$ the pressure :

\begin{align*}
-\eta_{water} \Delta u + \nabla p = 0 \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B\\ 
div(u)=0 \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B\\
u= \omega \times (x-x_B) \text{ on } \partial B\\ 
u \underset{|x| \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\\
\int_{\partial B} \sigma n \times (x-x_B) \ \mathrm{dx} + \tau  = 
0\end{align*}
where

- $\sigma:= 2 D(u) - p I_3$ is the Cauchy stress tensor
- $x_B$ is the center of mass of  $B$
- $w$ is the angular velocity of the fluid at $\partial B$, it is determined through the balance of torques $\int_{\partial B} \sigma n \times (x-x_B) \ \mathrm{dx}+ \tau = 
  0$

I would like to calculate the bulk stress defined as

$$\Sigma := \int_{\partial B} \sigma n \otimes x \ \mathrm{dx} - \left( \frac{1}{3} \int_{\partial B} \sigma n \cdot x \ \mathrm{dx} \right) \ I_3.$$

This quantity should depend on the shape of $B$ and the imposed moment $\tau$. I am interesed in several case :

- $B$ is a sphere of radius $r$, centered in $0$ and $\tau$ is a constant vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
- $B$ is a prolate ellipsoid parametrized by its orientation $d$ and the size of its 3 axis : $a \times a \times b$, centered in $0$ and $\tau$ is a constant vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
- The two last cases, but this time $\tau$ is a Brownian motion or white noise, characterizing the tumbling of the particle.

I am looking for a way to calculate this. I have already looked in the book "*Microhydrodynamics principles and selected applications*" written by Sangtae Kim, which gives calculation for the disturbance field of a sphere or a prolate ellipsoid, but there are no imposed moment $\tau$ on the particle surface. I've also looked in "*A physical introduction to suspension dynamics* " by Elisabeth Guazzelli but without sucess.